# _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); exception when I want to delete[] variable initiated with new

Tags: c++, arrays, c, new-operator, delete-operator

I was searching for the solution but found nothing what could help me with my problem.

**EDIT** I cannot use stl library in this project (so std::string, std:vector, std::cout etc. are out)

I am initiating my 2 dimension array of chars like that:

```cpp
char** string = new char*[MAX_MENU]; // MAX_MENU is 3 in my case
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU; i++) {
    string[i] = new char[20];
}
string[0] = "Start";
string[1] = "Leaderboard";
string[2] = "Quit";
```

Then when I quit the application I call this function:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU; i++) {
    delete[] string[i];
}
delete[] string;
```

The problem is with deleting the string[i]. When I don't delete it the problem doesn't occur but I don't want to leak the memory.

```cpp
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); // (X) - here is the exception
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: When using C++ prefer `std::vector` and `std::string` to using `new` and `delete`.  Also please post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem so we can test it.

Comment: `string[0] = "Start"` assigns the pointer from a string literal and leaks the originally new'd memory.  Use `std::vector<std::string>>` instead.

Comment: well, we cannot use stl library for this project .-.

Comment: now I edited the post, sorry for this

Comment: @G.M. you should write an answer

Comment: @SAMI _"well, we cannot use stl library for this project "_ Other than this code needs to run in an extremely memory restricted embedded environment, I cannot think of any reason why not, and in that case using `new` manually would be the wrong way to go either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, the following statement...

```
string[0] = "Start";
```

actually assigns the pointer associated with the string literal `"Start"` to `string[0]` and the original chunk of 20 chars allocated for and pointed to by `string[0]` is lost/leaked.

If you really can't use `std::vector`, `std::string` etc. then you can still make use of e.g. [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy).  So the code would then be something like...

```
char** string = new char*[MAX_MENU]; // MAX_MENU is 3 in my case
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU; i++) {
    string[i] = new char[20];
    string[i][0] = '\0';
}
strncpy(string[0], "Start", 20);
strncpy(string[1], "Leaderboard", 20);
strncpy(string[2], "Quit", 20);
```

Note that I've added `string[i][0] = '\0'` immediately after each `string[i]` is new'd to ensure null termination.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @G.M. I found the solutiin which is pretty easy

I just removed this part of the code

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU; i++) {
    delete[] string[i];
}
```

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU; i++) {
    string[i] = new char[20];
}
```

It seems to be no memory leak but I will leave programme running for about an hour to check the graph